# Joining tbl1 to select statement twice with join to tbl2 that also joins to tbl3

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, join, multiple-columns

I'm using SQL server manger.

I have 3 tables

[image: Tables snapshot and Query Aim]

I need a query that pulls t1 ands add an Origin Basin and a Destination Basin.

So far I have the following:

```
  select T1.[Country (destination)], T3.AreaName
         From T1
         left outer join T2 on
         T1.[Country (destination)] = T2.CountryName
         inner join T3 on 
         T2.AreaID = T3.AreaID 
         inner join T3 on
         T2.AreaID = T3.AreaID
```

Which returns:

Country | Area
However, I'm having trouble doing this for the second country column. I believe you use aliases. I've tried:

```
    select (select AreaName
        FROM T3
        where T3.AreaID = T2.AreaID) as 'Area Imp',
            (select AreaID
                From T2
                where T2.CountryName = T1.[Country (origin)]) as 'x',
    (select AreaID
        From T2
        where T2.CountryName = T1.[Country (destination)]) as 'y'
    FROM T1
```

But I can't get it to work.

Comment: where is second country column in T2 ?

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need to do:

```
select t1.date, t1.country_destination, t1.country_origin, destination_area.AreaName as area_destination, origin_area.AreaName as area_origin
from t1 as t1 join t2 as destination on t1.country_destination = destination.countryname
              join t2 as origin on t1.country_origin = origin.countryname

              join t3 as destination_area on t2.areaid = destination_area.areaid
              join t3 as origin_area on t2.areaid = origin_area.areaid
```

You will need to join with the same table twice, both for `t2` and `t3` so that you get the matching records for your needs.
It helps usually to put aliases that match the purpose of the join (in this case, `destination` and `origin`) when writing the query.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're trying to do is something like this:

```
 select T1.*, T3dest.AreaName, T3orig.AreaName
 From
     T1
        inner join
     T2 T2dest on
        T1.[Country (destination)] = T2dest.CountryName
        inner join
     T3 T3dest on 
        T2dest.AreaID = T3dest.AreaID 
        inner join
     T2 T2orig on
        T1.[Country (origin)] = T2orig.CountryName
        inner join
     T3 T3orig on
        T2orig.AreaID = T3orig.AreaID
```

Note that I've switched to `inner join`s throughout, at the moment. If you do want `left join` semantics, you either need to use those for all of the joins to the `T2` and `T3` tables or you need to change the join order (so that the relevant `T3` joins to the `T2` tables occur before the attempted join with `T1`). It's not clear from the sample data if that's required, however.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, You would still want to join on area id's

```
select T1.Date,T1.[Country (destination)], null [Country (origin)],  T3.AreaName [AreaName(Destination)], null [AreaName(Origin)]
         From T1
         left outer join T2 on
         T1.[Country (destination)] = T2.CountryName
         inner join T3 on 
         T2.AreaID = T3.AreaID 

union all

select T1.Date,null [Country (destination)],  t1.[Country (origin)],  Null [AreaName(Destination)], t3. [AreaName(Origin)]
         From T1
         left outer join T2 on
         T1.[Country (Origin)] = T2.CountryName
         inner join T3 on 
         T2.AreaID = T3.AreaID
```